# Flutter WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://broker.emqx.io:8084#' was not upgraded to websocket

Tags: flutter, dart, mqtt

Unhandled Exception: WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://broker.emqx.io:8084#' was not upgraded to websocket

i'm change other host with port ,but also happen this issue

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';


final client = MqttServerClient('wss://broker.emqx.io', '');
connect() async {
  client.useWebSocket = true;
  client.port = 8084; // ( or whatever your wss port is)
  client.websocketProtocols = MqttClientConstants.protocolsSingleDefault;
  client.logging(on: false);
  client.setProtocolV311();
  client.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
  final connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
      .withClientIdentifier('mqttx_93ffp4ak')
      .withWillTopic('willtopic') // If you set this you must set a will message
      .withWillMessage('My Will message')
      .startClean() // Non persistent session for testing
      .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
  print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connecting....');
  client.connectionMessage = connMess;
  client.websocketProtocols = ['mqtt'];
  try {
    await client.connect();
  } on NoConnectionException catch (e) {
    // Raised by the client when connection fails.
    print('EXAMPLE::client exception - $e');
    client.disconnect();
    exit(-1);
  } on SocketException catch (e) {
    // Raised by the socket layer
    print('EXAMPLE::socket exception - $e');
    client.disconnect();
    exit(-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: There are 2 things that error occurs, On the websocket itself, Or passing data. On the package it only use is to connect and receive data or send.

Comment: Ensure that you really added this package ```mqtt_client``` correctly, then run ```flutter pub get```.

Comment: probably `clientId` is not correct.

Comment: The URL should be `wss://broker.emqx.io/mqtt`.

Comment: i use `newest mqtt_client`.
the `clientId` is correct.
i use  `http://www.emqx.io/online-mqtt-client` this website test mqtt, this mqtt config can run

Comment: The online client defaults to a path of `/mqtt`. If you clear that then it will fail to connect too.